# xmllint fails to parse schematron with attribute

Tags: xml, xmllint, schematron

I am recieving an error when I attempt to validate against a schematron using xmllint.

I am looking to test XML elements that are marked with a particular attribute. So using the example from http://schematron.com

```
<Person Title="Mr">
    <Name>Eddie</Name>
    <Gender>Male</Gender>
</Person>
```

I modify the sample schematron to only select the person if they have a title of 'Mr':

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<sch:schema xmlns:sch="http://www.ascc.net/xml/schematron">
    <sch:pattern name="Check co-occurrence constraints">
        <sch:rule context="Person[@Title='Mr']">
            <sch:assert test="(@Title = 'Mr' and Gender = 'Male') or @Title != 'Mr'">If the Title is "Mr" then the gender of the person must be "Male".</sch:assert>
        </sch:rule>
    </sch:pattern>
</sch:schema>
```

Error message

```
$ xmllint --schematron sample-schematron.schema.xml sample-schematron.xml
sample-schematron.schema.xml:11: element rule: Schemas parser error : Failed to compile context expression Person[@Title='Mr']
Schematron schema sample-schematron.schema.xml failed to compile

$ xmllint --version
xmllint: using libxml version 20706
   compiled with: Threads Tree Output Push Reader Patterns Writer SAXv1 FTP HTTP DTDValid HTML Legacy C14N Catalog XPath XPointer XInclude Iconv ISO8859X Unicode Regexps Automata Expr Schemas Schematron Modules Debug Zlib
```

Any suggestions on how I can achieve this?

Comment: It works if you change the `context` expression to just `Person`.

Comment: Thats the problem. How does one apply a filter on an attribute?

Comment: Why do you need that? As far as I can tell, the rule works as expected with just `Person`.

Comment: Because while schematron's example illustrates their point. In my real world case, I am dealing with more than one record and they differ by attribute.